# Ivory Python Belly turned Dark Green

Tags: health, reptiles, snakes

I got a Ivory Ball Python back in March and even though his lower jaw was a little deformed (it was a bit shorter than his tip but he still was able to feed correctly) we loved him.

Unfortunately he passed away tonight while in his humidity box which is alarming since he was in shed and he knows how to get out of the box easily. Anyhow he wasn’t moving and I knew at that moment he was gone. He wasn’t burned or anything but my husband and I did notice a nickel sized circle of dark green on his underbelly. I can’t find anything on google that looks like it, it was NOT scale rot. We just want closure mainly in knowing if he might’ve also had a disease along with his odd jaw.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Sorry to hear of your loss.

Comment: Can you provide pictures? It might help telling what happened.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search led me to the following bit of information:

> I think that's actually her gall bladder?
>
> It's quite common to see it in deceased animals.
>   <sub>https://ball-pythons.net/forums/showthread.php?133545-URGENT!-death-caused-by-internal-something!!!!!&s=a1d152abe1e3880c35cce13f829e260f&p=1462887&viewfull=1#post1462887</sub>

This suggests that it's not necessarily a cause of death, but could as well be the aftermath of the animal dying.

Maybe a veterinarian knows more about this phenomenon.